# Problemas ao abrir conexão com JSF e JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jsf-2.2

Há algo de errado no meu `persistence.xml`? Não consigo abrir a conexão.

O meu Bean está assim:

```java
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import br.com.casadocodigo.jsfjpa.entities.Automovel;
import br.com.casadocodigo.jsfjpa.persistence.JPAUtil;

@ManagedBean
public class AutomovelBean {

    private Automovel automovel = new Automovel();

    private List<Automovel> automoveis;


    public Automovel getAutomovel() {
        return automovel;
    }   

    public void setAutomovel(Automovel automovel) {
        this.automovel = automovel;
    }

    public void salva(Automovel automovel) {

        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        em.persist(automovel);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        System.out.println("Marca: " + automovel.getMarca());
    }

    public List<Automovel> getAutomoveis() {

        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();

        Query q = em.createQuery("select a from Automovel a", Automovel.class);

        this.automoveis = q.getResultList();
        em.close();
        return automoveis;
    }

}
```

JPAUtil:

```java
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class JPAUtil {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Arquivo Xhtml:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Cadastro de Automoveis</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                Marca: <h:inputText value="#{automovelBean.automovel.marca}" /><br/>

                Modelo: <h:inputText value="#{automovelBean.automovel.modelo}"/><br/>

                Ano de Fabricacão: <h:inputText value="#{automovelBean.automovel.anoFabricacao}"/><br/>

                Ano do Modelo: <h:inputText value="#{automovelBean.automovel.anoModelo}"/><br/>

                Observações: <h:inputTextarea value="#{automovelBean.automovel.observacoes}"/><br/>

                <h:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{automovelBean.salva(automovelBean.automovel)}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

E o persistence:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/automoveis" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

O erro que está acontecendo:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

type: Exception report

message: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception: 

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: cara, vc adicionou o driver de conexão ao seu `lib`?
além disso, falta vc declarar as suas entidades ao `persistence.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Realmente exitem alguns problemas com seu arquivo `persistence.xml`, porém não ficou claro se o problema é especificamente no `persistence.xml`.

- Verifique se está tudo ok com seu Driver de conexão do MySql;

  - Verifique se a base de dados que vc criou está com o mesmo nome declarado no seu `persistence.xml`
  - No seu `persistence.xml` está faltando a declaração de suas entidades
    que serão tabelas na base de dados.  vc terá que adicionar o *fully

    qualified name* dentro das `tags` `<class></class>`, tenha cuidado com a hierarquia das `tags`;
  - Adicione a declaração do provedor do JPA Hibernate (relativo a versão do arquivo `persistence.xml` que é 2.0);

  `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`

  - retire o `static` do seu método `getEntityManager()` na classe JPAUtil.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema. O MySQL não estava instalado.

Comment: @GabrielFaria, pode crer. Agora só falta encerrar a pergunta. :)

Answer (score 0):

Tente acrescentar o seguinte no seu `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Acrescente isso antes do `<properties>`.

Além disso, se isso não resolver, então poste o seu stacktrace completo para que possamos te ajudar melhor. Digo isso porque o stacktrace parece não estar completo. Por favor, coloque-o completo para que possamos te ajudar. Claramente é um problema na conexão com o banco de dados, mas com o stacktrace incompleto não dá para saber exatamente qual.

Além disso, observo que a sua arquitetura tem um problema por permitir o acesso aos beans de entidades após o `EntityManager` ter sido fechado e permitir que os mesmos sejam manipulados diretamente pelo JSF. Isso não necessariamente fará o seu código falhar ou ter algum tipo de bug sério, mas é uma arquitetura frágil na qual é muito fácil fazer-se algo errado. O motivo é que algumas propriedades podem ser *lazy*, e ao acessá-las no JSF após o fechamento do `EntityManager` você vai tomar um `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`. Para evitar ter que controlar detalhadamente isso, o que é algo bem chato e muito propenso a erros bobos, recomendo você usar uma classe bean para falar com o JSF e uma classe bean diferente (o bean de entidade) para falar com o Hibernate/JPA, e no managed bean você faz alguma coisa que converta uma em outra sem nunca deixar que o bean de entidade possa ser referenciado após o `EntityManager` ter sido fechado. Além disso, com esta abordagem, você também desacopla a estrutura das páginas de visualização da estrutura do mapeamento objeto/relacional do banco de dados.

Outro problema é que se os seus métodos de negócio falharem com alguma exceção após o `EntityManager` ter sido criado, ele não será fechado e ficará órfão. Para evitar isso, feche o `EntityManager` em blocos `finally`.

Por fim, substitua isso:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select a from Automovel a", Automovel.class);
```

Por isso:

```
TypedQuery<Automovel> q = em.createQuery("select a from Automovel a", Automovel.class);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Victor. Eu estou estudando com um livro e estou no começo. no github do livro há esses alterações de "Query q", para "TypedQuery<Automovel>", porém, como estou no começo o autor está mostrando passo a passo. Eu acrescentei antes do <properties> o <Provider> que você enviou, mas não deu certo, vou postar o stacktrace completo. obrigado